# More Speed in python

Tags: python, performance, synchronization, processing-efficiency

I'm working on synchronization of complex networks using Kuramoto model . I wrote a program that is very slow to run . It's about 14 days running and still didn't finish. in summary, there are N nodes in a random network using this dynamics:

```
d(theta)[i]/dt = K/k[i]*sum(adjancy_matrix[i,j]*sin(teta[j]-teta[i]))
```

that `theta[i]` is the phase of each node that have initial random data . 
adjancy matrix is an adjacency matrix between nodes. and `k[i]` is the order of each node and lastly `K=10` and the dt s

this dynamics make the system nodes change in attraction with other nodes till the system goes to the synchronized system .

There were physics introduction. the program is:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import abs
from random import random
from time import time
from math import pi,sin,cos,exp
import cmath
start=time()
def initial_phase(graph):
    phase_list=[]
    for i in range(len(graph)):
        phase_list.append((random()-0.5)*2*np.pi)
    return np.array(phase_list)
def graph_degree(graph):
    degree_list=[]
    for i in range(len(G)):
        degree_list.append(graph.degree(i))
    return np.array(degree_list)
t_start=0;t_end=1;dt=0.1
tpoints=np.arange(t_start,t_end,dt)
G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(10,2,0.03,seed= None)
adj_matrix=nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
def rung_kutta(graph,adjancy_matrix,teta,K,k): 
    list_sum=[] ; i_teta=[]
    for i in range(len(graph)) :
        sum_phase=0
        for j in range(len(graph)):
             sum_phase=sum_phase+adjancy_matrix[i,j]*np.sin(teta[j]-teta[i])
        d=(cos(teta[i])+1j*sin(teta[i]))
        i_teta.append(d)
        list_sum.append((K/k[i])*sum_phase)
    return np.array(list_sum),np.array(i_teta)
print(rung_kutta(G,adj_matrix,initial_phase(G),10,graph_degree(G)))
teta_point=[] ; r=[] 
teta_0=initial_phase(G)
degree=graph_degree(G)
c=np.zeros((len(teta_0), len(teta_0)))
for t in tpoints : 
    teta_point.append(teta_0)
    a=[];a.append(teta_0)
    k1=rung_kutta(G,adj_matrix,teta_0,10,degree)[0]*dt
    k2=rung_kutta(G,adj_matrix,teta_0+(k1/2),10,degree)[0]*dt
    k3=rung_kutta(G,adj_matrix,teta_0+(k2/2),10,degree)[0]*dt
    k4=rung_kutta(G,adj_matrix,teta_0+(k3),10,degree)[0]*dt
    teta_0=teta_0+(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
    gh=sum(rung_kutta(G,adj_matrix,teta_0,10,degree)[1])
    r.append(abs(gh)/len(G))
    for i in range(len(c)):
        for j in range(len(c)):
            c[i][j]=c[i][j]+np.cos(a[0][i]-a[0][j])

print(c/len(tpoints))
print(r)
plt.plot(tpoints,r)
plt.show()
print((np.array(teta_point))[-1,:])
pco=plt.pcolor(c/len(tpoints),cmap='jet')
print(time()-start)
plt.imshow(c/len(tpoints),cmap='jet')
plt.colorbar(pco,label='Correlation')
plt.show()
```

My question is that, is it possible to write this program parallel? or is it possible to write it more efficient to speed it up?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Several loops of yours can be vectorised or paralellised. It is probably not feasible to do with just Python.

Comment: I'm sorry, you said 14 days? How many operations exactly are you doing here? Anyway, what you're looking for is multiprocessing and probably multiprocessing.pool.

Comment: you mean I should write it in C or something like that ?

Comment: You might want to try Cython first, since it is the least effort from where you are. It really depends on how much time is spent in which section. C and C++ would allow you to stay with Python otherwise by writing an extension or bindings. Julia would be easy to get in to, but is much better for vectorisation than parallelisation. You might be lucky using Python‘s multiprocessing, but only if the data passed around is small.